# Smoking tik during Ramadan

Tags: sin

I would like to know that if you smoke drugs during Ramadan and felt bad about what you did because it's a holy month and repents to Allah and cleans himself with the Ramadan wash and make his niya to fast the following day and want to start fresh and be a better person from there will it be accepted?